# Highlight Column VBA EXCEL Starting at Second Column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to highlight a column starting from row 2 this is my code below

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Sheets("OPEN - REPEAT").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks(var2).Sheets("OPEN - REPEAT").Columns("A2" & Lastrow).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

I keep getting the following error *Application or Object Defined error 1004*
any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the last column you want colored.  It is not set.

Comment: It might be any number I thought that is how I set it?

Comment: Third line should be `Workbooks(var2).Sheets("OPEN - REPEAT").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).Interior.Color = vbYellow

Comment: Last row is a number.  It represent the last row with a value in Column A.  It has no column denotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Columns("A2" & Lastrow)` is all wrong.  Use `.Range` and you also need to specify an end column and end row, so it should look like this:

```
Workbooks(var2).Sheets("OPEN - REPEAT").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Comment: (@AngatvirSanghera - If that solved your issue, you can mark the post as The Answer, by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows)

Comment: Hi there is an issue with this it ends up highlighting 24000 lines instead of the ones used

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera The issue would be with how you assign the value of `Lastrow`.  After you assign that value, check what it is with a `MsgBox` or `Deubg.Print`, and then find out why it's getting assigned an incorrect value.